# Images not resized but cropped

Tags: html, css, image, resize, crop

I have a very odd problem. The first `image` is showing up correctly, but `eng` and `slo` are showing up cropped and not resized down to 5% height and width or 200px height and width. I am currently clueless as to why this is happening, because `image` is identical to both `eng` and `slo`. I have tried this in different browsers, but without success.
Here is the link to the picture if it helps:

[image]

This is the code I am using on my website:

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url("ninabg.jpg") left top no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.image {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("logo2fix.png");
    position:absolute;
    right:1%;
    bottom:3%;
    height:40%;
    width:35%;
}

.slo {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("slo.png");
    position:absolute;
    height:5%;
    width:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:21%;

}

.eng {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url("eng.png");
    position:absolute;
    right:12%;
    bottom:10%;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- META -->
        <title>Nina Rakovec</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Profesionalna igralka" />

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="eng"></div>
            <div class="slo"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please apply `background-size: cover` to one of these images and see if that resolves your problem?

Comment: Hell yeah! :D It works, I'm not exactly sure what that does, but thanks so much for the answer, it's working now :)

Comment: Actually none of your images is resized. By default they are displaying in their original dimensions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size  (background-size) property controls the size and you can set it to be whatever the dimension you want the image to be resized  to (akin to `img width="x" height="y"`. `cover` setting scales it down along the longer edge (so possibly some cropping will still occur). There's also `contain` setting (with which it will display some background).